# ASP.NET : Avoid multipile clicks on a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress [ASPxButton](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxButtontopic), and I was wondering how can I prevent the user from clicking the button more then once?

Basically it does an update/insert statement.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the following code:

```
var buttonClicked = false;

function MyBtnClick(s,e){
  if(buttonClicked) return;
  buttonClicked = true;
  // do something
}

<ASPxButton id="btn" runat="server">
  <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e) { MyBtnClick(s,e); } "/>
</ASPxButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the client side, you can disable it when it's clicked.

On the server side, my favourite approach is generally to send a nonce with the form data, and then reject duplicate nonces.

As always, client side validates in a fast and (hopefully) friendly way, server side validates for sure even if client side code suffers from some unexpected browser issue, or someone is deliberately messing things up.

Comment: If you would disable it client-side when it is clicked, it will not trigger the server-side `OnClick` method anymore.

Comment: @UweKeim As always, client side validates in a fast and (hopefully) friendly way, server side validates for sure even if client side code suffers from some unexpected browser issue, or someone is deliberately messing things up.

Comment: My point is that if you disable the `ASPxButton` control client-side, you will break the functionality of the control :-)

Comment: @UweKeim I think I get you now, though surely you don't want it to function any more?

Comment: The ideal behaviour would be: 1.) User clicking, 2.) Disabling control, 3.) Posting to server. Unfortunately, step 2 prevents step 3. Thus the somewhat complicated [answer of the DevExpress team](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3565612/107625) to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about aspxbutton specifically but in general you will have something like this on the onclick attribute of the control.

```
onclick="this.disabled=true;"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you run the update query simply add to the start of the code:

```
ButtonNameOrID.Enabled = False // add ; to end if C#
```

Then at the end of the code, add:

```
ButtonNameOrID.Enabled = True // add ; to end if C#
```

This is will disable/enable the button from your C# or VB code.

Comment: That doesn't work, because the request is processed on the server, before the client is updated. So the button will never be disabled on the client.